# hs_err A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environmen

Tags: tomcat, jvm, apache-poi, hs-err

**I tried to use the POI in the web application to read a 65000 rows, 21 columns of excel table, I got this error. Tomcat also stopped.**
    Current thread (0x00007f32f8e75000):  JavaThread "http-bio-18080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=25287, stack(0x00007f32958e9000,0x00007f329596a000)]

```
siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f32f8e75000, RCX=0x0000000000000420, RDX=0x00007f3301111210
RSP=0x00007f329595fa30, RBP=0x00007f329595fab0, RSI=0x00007f32f8e75000, RDI=0x00007f329595fa40
R8 =0x00007f32e0549a60, R9 =0x000000000000002c, R10=0x000000000000002b, R11=0x0000000000000002
R12=0x0000000000000420, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f329595fa40, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007f330081aca2, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0xffff000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f32f8e75000 is a thread
RCX=0x0000000000000420 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f3301111210: <offset 0xfcc210> in /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f3300145000
RSP=0x00007f329595fa30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f32f8e75000
RBP=0x00007f329595fab0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f32f8e75000
RSI=0x00007f32f8e75000 is a thread
RDI=0x00007f329595fa40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f32f8e75000
R8 =0x00007f32e0549a60 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000000000002c is an unknown value
R10=0x000000000000002b is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000420 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007f329595fa40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f32f8e75000
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f32958e9000,0x00007f329596a000],  sp=0x00007f329595fa30,  free space=474k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x6d5ca2]  jni_SetByteArrayRegion+0xc2
C  [libjrebel64.so+0x7bca]  classFileLoadHook.part.0+0xaa

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V+5
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace()V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)V+47
J 25373 C1 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document; (87 bytes) @ 0x00007f32ec89b99c [0x00007f32ec89b880+0x11c]
j  javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;+35
j  org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;+4
j  org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaType;Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;+1
j
```

Comment: The crash log clearly says the problem has happened in JRebel agent library.  
Report the problem to [ZeroTurnaround](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/support/).

Comment: @ZeroTurnaround The crash happened in the JVM itself, but that JRebel library certainly could have contributed to the crash. 李建明, can you reproduce the crash when the JRebel agent is not attached to the JVM? If so, this is a JVM bug. If not, it's probably JRebel's fault and you'll need to talk to them.

Comment: Crash logs are broken, please share the complete crash logs.